# Query multiple XML values

Tags: sql-server, xml

```
<book>
<author>Bob Villa</author>
<author>Tom Whatever</author>
<author>Sarah kajdl</author>
</book>
```

How would I query for any record that had an author of Tom Whatever? Most query examples I've seen reference the value [x], but I want to search all authors.

```
DECLARE @author as varchar(100)
SET @author = 'Tom Whatever'
SELECT xmlfield.value('/book/author')
WHERE xmlfield.value('/book/author') = @author
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the answer

```
DECLARE @x XML 
SET @x = '<book>
<author>Bob Villa</author>
<author>Tom Whatever</author>
<author>Sarah kajdl</author>
</book>'

DECLARE @author AS VARCHAR(100)
SET @author = 'Tom Whatever'
SELECT c.value('.' ,'VARCHAR(100)')
FROM   @x.nodes('book/author') AS t(c)
WHERE   c.value('.' ,'VARCHAR(8000)') = @author
```

Comment: How about if I want to query all appearance of the tag 'author' in this case? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26426412/how-to-ensure-the-sql-is-able-to-read-all-xml-tag-data

Answer (score 3):

If you just want the value from an XML variable you can use the `value` method directly and use `sql:variable` in your XPath expression:

```
SELECT @XML.value('(/book/author[.=sql:variable("@author")])[1]', 'nvarchar(50)')
```

If you have your XML in a table and want the rows where there is an author you can use `exist`.

```
select *
from YourTable
where XMLCol.exist('/book/author[.=sql:variable("@author")]') = 1
```

And then you can of course combine them.

```
select XMLCol.value('(/book/author[.=sql:variable("@author")])[1]', 'nvarchar(50)')
from YourTable
where XMLCol.exist('/book/author[.=sql:variable("@author")]') = 1
```