# How to ensure the SQL is able to read all XML tag data

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, xml

I have the following XML data in a SQL table column:

```
<root>
    <Physicians>
        <name></name>
        <picture></picture>
        <gender></gender>
        <langAccept>English</langAccept>
        <langAccept>Spanish</langAccept> (can appear more times)
        <insAccept>Aetna</insAccept>
        <insAccept>BCBS</insAccept> (can appear more times)
        <specialty></specialty>
        <specialty2></specialty2>
        <specialty3></specialty3>
    </Physicians>
</root>
```

The `langAccept` and `insAccept` can appear multiple times, and there is no way to know how many times.

I have the following SQL query which currently is not taking into account 'langAccept' and 'insAccept' tags:

```
DECLARE @strProvider varchar(200)
SET @strProvider = '' --The Provider DropDownList

DECLARE @strSpecialty varchar(200)
SET @strSpecialty = '' --The Specialty DropDownList

DECLARE @strLocation varchar(200)
SET @strLocation = '' --The Location DropDownList

DECLARE @strGender varchar(200)
SET @strGender = '' --The Gender DropDownList

DECLARE @strInsurance varchar(200)
SET @strInsurance = '' --The Insurance DropDownList

DECLARE @strLanguage varchar(200)
SET @strLanguage = '' --The Language DropDownList


SELECT
    [content_title] AS [Physician Name]
    , [content_status] AS [Status]
    , CAST([content_html] AS XML).value('(root/Physicians/picture/img/@src)[1]','varchar(255)') AS [Image]
    , dbo.usp_ClearHTMLTags(CONVERT(nvarchar(600), CAST([content_html] AS XML).query('root/Physicians/gender'))) AS [Gender]
    , CAST([content_html] AS XML).query('/root/Physicians/OfficeLocations/office1/a') AS [Office1]
    , CAST([content_html] AS XML).query('/root/Physicians/OfficeLocations/office2/a') AS [Office2]
    , CAST([content_html] AS XML).query('/root/Physicians/OfficeLocations/office3/a') AS [Office3]
    , CAST([content_html] AS XML).query('/root/Physicians/OfficeLocations/office4/a') AS [Office4]
    , CAST ([content_html] AS XML).query('/root/Physicians/specialty/a') AS [Specialty1]
    , CAST ([content_html] AS XML).query('/root/Physicians/specialty2/a') AS [Specialty2]
FROM
    [MYDB].[dbo].[content]
WHERE
    [folder_id] = '188'
    AND
    (content_html LIKE '%<gender>%'+ @strGender+'%</gender>%')
    AND
    (content_html LIKE '%'+@strSpecialty+'%')
    AND
    (content_html LIKE '%'+@strLocation+'%')
    AND
    (content_status = 'A')
ORDER BY
    [content_title]
```

I will be taking that data and writing to a repeater in my ASP.net page using C# as code-behind.

How can I modify my SQL query so that it takes the value for each `langAccept` and `insAccept` tag (as many times as it appears).

Comment: This should duplicate rows or put into one row (like `English, Spanish`) ?

Comment: If I can even take them put it in a column by CSV, I can manipulate them in the code-behind. I think adding a column and inserting each occurance by CSV is the better route for my purpose.

Comment: Column values that uses comma separators are not a good idea. That's an example of a poor database design. Instead, you should seek to have a properly normalized database, it will be much easier to obtain data from.

Comment: Because it is the first time I am using it, I an open for suggestion and helped :). Pretty much this query will return the result which I will be displaying it in the front end as a result. Sometime those tags will appear 10+ times, so does it make sense to create 10+ rows in a table?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You *can* handle any number of nodes that might repeat - but mind you, this will always create numerous rows for a single entry `<Physician>`.

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Content TABLE (ID INT NOT NULL, XmlDAta XML)
INSERT INTO @content VALUES(1, '<root>
    <Physicians>
        <name>Dr. Excellent</name>
        <picture></picture>
        <gender>Male</gender>
        <langAccept>English</langAccept>
        <langAccept>Spanish</langAccept> 
        <insAccept>Aetna</insAccept>
        <insAccept>BCBS</insAccept> 
        <specialty></specialty>
        <specialty2></specialty2>
        <specialty3></specialty3>
    </Physicians>
</root>')

SELECT
    ID,
    PhysicianName = XC.value('(name)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    Gender = XC.value('(gender)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    LangSpoken = XLang.value('.', 'varchar(20)'),
    InsAccepted = XIns.value('.', 'varchar(50)')
FROM
    @Content
CROSS APPLY
    XmlData.nodes('/root/Physicians') AS XT(XC)
CROSS APPLY
    XC.nodes('langAccept') AS XT2(XLang)
CROSS APPLY
    XC.nodes('insAccept') AS XT3(XIns)
```

By using the `.nodes()` on both the `langAccept` and `insAccept` inside the `<Physician>` node, you get all the defined values - but you end up with several relational rows for a single `<Physican>` node:

[image]

**Update:** to get the data from your own existing table, use this:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    PhysicianName = XC.value('(name)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    Gender = XC.value('(gender)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    LangSpoken = XLang.value('.', 'varchar(20)'),
    InsAccepted = XIns.value('.', 'varchar(50)')
FROM
    [MyDB].[dbo].Content
CROSS APPLY
    CAST(content_html AS XML).nodes('/root/Physicians') AS XT(XC)
CROSS APPLY
    XC.nodes('langAccept') AS XT2(XLang)
CROSS APPLY
    XC.nodes('insAccept') AS XT3(XIns)
```

Comment: Unfortunately the XML is being read from a SQL table and I am not sure how many times the TAG will appear. I updated my question, the XML is already inside a SQL table column and not in a file, my apology.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge: my post works off of a SQL Server table .... just replace my `@Content` with `[MYDB].[dbo].[content]` and off you go

Comment: `DECLARE @Content [dbo].[content]`?

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge: no - replace my `@Content` in the `SELECT` statement with your own database name .... updated my response

Comment: So I can get all the data in that case. So I don't have to use `.query()` anymore and don't need this anymore: `/root/Physicians/OfficeLocations/office1/a`?

Comment: I get the following error: `The XMLDT method 'nodes' can only be invoked on columns of type xml.` and for the `Physician Name` I am getting this error: `Invalid column name 'XmlData'.`

Comment: How do I cross apply other columns as well?

Comment: Well first of all: you need to use **your** column name (instead of `XmlData`). And secondly: this column has to be of **type** `XML` for this to work!

Comment: Can I cast it as XML inside the query? changing to `content_html` as the column name removed the first error.

Comment: Yes - if you *must* - but really: if the data looks like XML, quacks like XML, smells like XML - it's **XML** and should be **stored** as `XML` !!

Comment: It is from a CMS so unfortunately I do not have any control. How would I convert it to XML in this case?

Comment: I am getting an error: `Incorrect Syntax near the keyword 'AS'` (Thank you for the edit BTW)

Comment: @marc_s Even I am getting the same error  Incorrect Syntax near the keyword 'AS' Can you help out please ?

Comment: @marc_s one of the best answers (have seen like 50 of them), very practical, good balance of simplicity and advanced techniques

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this.
This is not the exact answer to your problem, but this might help  you solve your problem.

```
        DECLARE @Data XMl = '<root><Physicians><name>sajsj</name><picture/><gender/><langAccept>English</langAccept><langAccept>Spanish</langAccept> (can appear more times)<insAccept>Aetna</insAccept><insAccept>BCBS</insAccept> (can appear more times)<specialty/><specialty2/><specialty3/></Physicians></root>';

        ;WITH CTE AS (

        SELECT Dt.value('(name/text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS Name,
               Dt.query('(langAccept)') AS LangAccept,
               Dt.query('(insAccept)') AS InsAccept
        FROM 
        @Data.nodes('/root/Physicians') AS MyData(Dt)
        ),
        CteGetAllLangAccept AS 
        (

         SELECT 
         Ct.Name,
         Data.Lang.value('(.)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS [LangAcceptValue],
         NULL AS [InsAcceptDataValue]
         FROM  CTE Ct
         CROSS APPLY Ct.LangAccept.nodes('/langAccept') AS Data(Lang)

         ),
         CteGetInsAcceptData AS (
          SELECT 
         Ct.Name,
         NULL AS [LangAcceptValue],
         InsAcceptData.Ins.value('(.)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS [InsAcceptDataValue]
         FROM  CTE Ct
         CROSS APPLY Ct.InsAccept.nodes('/insAccept') AS InsAcceptData(Ins)
         )

         SELECT * FROM CteGetAllLangAccept![enter image description here][1]
         UNION 
         SELECT * FROM CteGetInsAcceptData;
```

[image: Check the output here.0]

Comment: Thank you for the response. The XML data is already inside a SQL table column and I am just reading from the column and stripping out the data. I have no doubt it works but mine isn't a file but a table column. How can I change the `@Data` to point to the table column rather than hard coded string? Should I get the value from the column and store it in a string and use that string for the `@Data` instead and use the above query?

Answer (score 1):

I think if you want to show it on the client side, it's easier to do several queries, one for doctors table, one for `langAccept` and one for `insAccept`:

```
declare @temp table (data xml)

insert into @temp (data)
select '<root>
    <Physicians>
        <name>House M.D.</name>
        <picture></picture>
        <gender>Male</gender>
        <langAccept>English</langAccept>
        <langAccept>Spanish</langAccept> 
        <insAccept>Aetna</insAccept>
        <insAccept>BCBS</insAccept> 
        <specialty></specialty>
        <specialty2></specialty2>
        <specialty3></specialty3>
    </Physicians>
    <Physicians>
        <name>Paracelsus</name>
        <picture></picture>
        <gender>Male</gender>
        <langAccept>German</langAccept>
        <langAccept>Latin</langAccept> 
        <specialty></specialty>
        <specialty2></specialty2>
        <specialty3></specialty3>
    </Physicians>    
</root>'

select
    t.c.value('name[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as name,
    t.c.value('gender[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as gender
from @temp as a
    cross apply a.data.nodes('root/Physicians') as t(c)
    
select
    t.c.value('name[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as name,
    l.c.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as langAccept
from @temp as a
    cross apply a.data.nodes('root/Physicians') as t(c)
    cross apply t.c.nodes('langAccept') as l(c)
    
select
    t.c.value('name[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as name,
    l.c.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as insAccept
from @temp as a
    cross apply a.data.nodes('root/Physicians') as t(c)
    cross apply t.c.nodes('insAccept') as l(c)
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The XML data is a column in a table so I would have to pull the column from the table and then extract